# sending objects to partials in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Folder structure,

```
..
/templates
|--/pages
  |--/myPage.hbs
|../partials
  |..myPartial.hbs
```

AFAIK, `grunt & node` are taking care of compiling and registering all the partials.

**myPartial.hbs**

```
<div>
    {{#page.myObj}}
    <span> {{a}} </span>
</div>
```

**myPage.hbs**,
I'm trying to do something like this,

```
---
myObj = {'a' : 1}
myObj2 = {'a' : 2}
---
{{> myPartial}}
```

How can I make my partial dynamic and take a parameter to show content depending on the object I pass it?

PS: I'm new to handlebars and taking over someone else's code, this is dummy code to show the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars partials take a second parameter which becomes the context for the partial:

```
{{> myPartial myObj}}

{{> myPartial myObj2}}
```